# All breakpoints are being disabled in Android Studio when debugging Flutter's code

Tags: flutter, google-chrome, breakpoints

I'm facing this problem which happens in both Chrome & Edge, as soon as I start debugging, all Breakpoints turn to disabled.

I tried doing a clean-up, then flutter-upgrade, cache-clean, computer restart, Invalidate Caches, Repair IDE, uninstall and reinstall Dart and Flutter Plugins but still no luck.

Everything works just fine if using the Emulator.

My tech stack and configuration here:

- Flutter (Channel stable, 3.16.9
- Android Studio Hedgehog | 2023.1.1 Patch 2
- Dart: 231.9411
- Flutter: 77.2.1 -Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22631.3085], locale en-US)
- Chrome Version 121.0.6167.140 (Official Build) (64-bit)

All breakpoints should remain active when launching the App.